# Output Parameter of Stored Procedure is not getting set

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rpc, odbc

So I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspUpdateOrInsertDataObjectValue 
    @ParentDataObjectId INT,
    @DataObjectName NVARCHAR(256),
    @DataObjectValue NVARCHAR(256),
    @ForceInsert BIT,
    @ReturnDataObjectId INT OUT
WITH RECOMPILE
AS 
BEGIN
    if @ForceInsert = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DataObjects SET Value=@DataObjectValue WHERE Name=@DataObjectName AND ParentDataObjectId=@ParentDataObjectId
    END
    if ( @ForceInsert = 1 ) OR ( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 )
    BEGIN
        --Spend time on the hierarchy id stuff only if we have to insert
        DECLARE @ParentTreeId HierarchyId
        DECLARE @LastChildTreeId HierarchyId
        SELECT @ParentTreeId = TreeId FROM DataObjects WHERE DataObjectId=@ParentDataObjectId
        SELECT @LastChildTreeId = MAX(TreeId) FROM DataObjects WHERE TreeId.GetAncestor(1)=@ParentTreeId
        INSERT INTO DataObjects ( Name, Value, ParentDataObjectId, TreeId ) VALUES ( @DataObjectName, @DataObjectValue, @ParentDataObjectId, @ParentTreeId.GetDescendant( @LastChildTreeId, NULL ) )
    END
    SELECT @ReturnDataObjectId = (SELECT TOP 1 DataObjectId FROM DataObjects WHERE Name=@DataObjectName AND ParentDataObjectId=@ParentDataObjectId ORDER BY DataObjectId DESC)
    RETURN 0
END
GO
```

`

And I'm executing it like this:

```
    int iParentDataObjectId = 1;
    int iDataObjectId = 0;
    SQLWCHAR    name[256];
    SQLWCHAR    value[256];

    _sntprintf_s( (wchar_t*)name, 256, _TRUNCATE, _T("%s"), pCDBDataObject->GetName() );
    _sntprintf_s( (wchar_t*)value, 256, _TRUNCATE, _T("%s"), pCDBDataObject->GetString() );

    result = SQLBindParameter( sqlStatementHandle, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &iParentDataObjectId, 0, NULL );
    result = SQLBindParameter( sqlStatementHandle, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WVARCHAR, 256, 0, name, 256, NULL );
    result = SQLBindParameter( sqlStatementHandle, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WVARCHAR, 256, 0, value, 256, NULL );
    result = SQLBindParameter( sqlStatementHandle, 4, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BIT, SQL_BIT, 1, 0, &forceInsert, 0, NULL );
    result = SQLBindParameter( sqlStatementHandle, 5, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &iDataObjectId, 0, NULL );

    result = SQLExecDirect( sqlStatementHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)_T("{CALL uspUpdateOrInsertDataObjectValue (?,?,?,?,?)}"), SQL_NTS );
```

'

The stored procedure executes properly and inserts or updates the database but iDataObjectId never changes.

However when I execute it like this in a script in Sql Server Management Studio:

```
DECLARE @testval int
EXECUTE uspUpdateOrInsertDataObjectValue 1, 'Config', 'testasdfasdfasdfas', 1, @testval OUT
SELECT * from DataObjects where DataObjectId=@testval
```

the output value is assigned to @testval and the subsequent select statement works just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you have SQL Profiler in your installation of SQL Server, you could try using it to see what the command that your application is sending to the server looks like. Maybe that can help you to figure out what is going on. (There may be other methods to get that query that do not rely on SQL Profiler and may in general be better too, though. I'm just suggesting what I know at this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a more careful examination of this example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403283.aspx

You need to clean out the result sets of the query(call) with SqlMoreResults before the output variables get set.  Not the behavior I would have expected but it was right there in the documentation.